multiple times addition of two columns with dplyr
Assume I have a tibble (in my example here only with four columns). In real I have two hourly time series therefore 2 times 24 columns:
s1.x,...,s24.x, s1.y,...,s24.y
Now I want to sum up column s1.x with s1.y, s2.x with s2.y to s24.x with s24.y.
a <- tibble(s1.x=2:7, s2.x=3:8, s1.y=4:9, s2.y=5:10)

a %>% 
  mutate(s1.tot=s1.x+s1.y, s2.tot=s2.x+s2.y)

How can I do this in a short (and elegant way) for all 24 hours?

I think your best option would be to pivot your data to long format.  That will make this operation - and, most likely, future steps in your process - far simpler.

You can use Map function:
n = 2      # for your data, use n = 24
a[paste0("s", 1:n, ".tot")] = Map(`+`, a[paste0("s", 1:n, ".x")], a[paste0("s", 1:n, ".y")])

# A tibble: 6 × 6
   s1.x  s2.x  s1.y  s2.y s1.tot s2.tot
  <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
1     2     3     4     5      6      8
2     3     4     5     6      8     10
3     4     5     6     7     10     12
4     5     6     7     8     12     14
5     6     7     8     9     14     16
6     7     8     9    10     16     18


Suggest automatically setting the value of n as n <- sum(endsWith(names(a), ".x"))

A base R solution
cbind(
    a,
    lapply(
        split.default(a, sub("\\..*", ".tot", names(a))),
        rowSums
    )
)

or even shorter
cbind(a, t(rowsum(t(a), sub("\\..*", ".tot", names(a)))))

which gives
  s1.x s2.x s1.y s2.y s1.tot s2.tot
1    2    3    4    5      6      8
2    3    4    5    6      8     10
3    4    5    6    7     10     12
4    5    6    7    8     12     14
5    6    7    8    9     14     16
6    7    8    9   10     16     18

Benchmarking
If you are care about the speed
edward <- function() {
    a %>%
        mutate(id = 1:nrow(a)) %>%
        pivot_longer(-id,
            names_to = c("s", ".value"),
            names_pattern = "(s\\d+).(.)"
        ) |>
        mutate(tot = x + y, .by = id) |>
        pivot_wider(names_from = s, values_from = c(x, y, tot), names_glue = "{s}.{.value}") %>%
        select(-id)
}


mael <- function() {
    a |>
        mutate(across(matches(".x$"), .names = "{gsub('x', '', .col)}tot") +
            across(matches(".y$")))
}

tic1 <- function() {
    cbind(
        a,
        lapply(
            split.default(a, sub("\\..*", ".tot", names(a))),
            rowSums
        )
    )
}

tic2 <- function() {
    cbind(a, t(rowsum(t(a), sub("\\..*", ".tot", names(a)))))
}

microbenchmark(
    edward(),
    mael(),
    tic1(),
    tic2(),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equivalent"
)

shows
Unit: relative
     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 edward() 43.286275 33.290854 29.937941 32.085324 30.763830 8.997682   100
   mael()  8.465686  7.081354  6.652635  6.930750  6.867252 2.572953   100
   tic1()  1.673039  1.469692  1.527453  1.417756  1.315485 1.425672   100
   tic2()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000   100


Maybe sub("\\..+", ".tot", names(a)) instead of paste0(sub("\\..*", "", names(a)), ".tot") ?

I would do it with two across in this case, although pivoting might be a better option for more complex operations.
library(dplyr)
a |> 
  mutate(across(matches(".x$"), .names = "{gsub('x', '', .col)}tot") + 
           across(matches(".y$")))

#   s1.x s2.x s1.y s2.y s1.tot s2.tot
# 1    2    3    4    5      6      8
# 2    3    4    5    6      8     10
# 3    4    5    6    7     10     12
# 4    5    6    7    8     12     14
# 5    6    7    8    9     14     16
# 6    7    8    9   10     16     18


One way is to pivot. But we need to add an id column to do the sum.
a %>% 
  mutate(id=1:nrow(a)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id,
               names_to=c("s", ".value"),
               names_pattern="(s\\d+).(.)") |>
  mutate(tot=x+y, .by=id) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from=s, values_from=c(x,y,tot), names_glue="{s}.{.value}")


# A tibble: 6 × 7
     id  s1.x  s2.x  s1.y  s2.y s1.tot s2.tot
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
1     1     2     3     4     5      6      8
2     2     3     4     5     6      8     10
3     3     4     5     6     7     10     12
4     4     5     6     7     8     12     14
5     5     6     7     8     9     14     16
6     6     7     8     9    10     16     18


Here's a general tidyverse solution - 24 hours, 7 days (series), 5 observations example.
# Pkgs and seed -----------------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(100)

# Toy data - 24 hours a day, 7 days, 5 observations -----------------------
my_df <- paste0(rep(paste0("s", str_pad(1:24, width = 2, pad = "0")), 7), ".", rep(letters[19:25], each = 24))
my_df <- as_tibble(matrix(sample(0:10, (7*24)* 5, replace = TRUE), nrow = 5, dimnames = list(rep(NA, 5), my_df)))

# code - Creates a list and reduces it ------------------------------------
new_df <- reduce(map(
  str_unique(str_extract(colnames(my_df), ".$")),
  \(i) rename_with(select(my_df, ends_with(i)), \(j) str_replace(j, paste0(i, "$"), "tot"))), 
  `+`)

# Output ------------------------------------------------------------------
select(my_df,contains("01"))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 7
#>   s01.s s01.t s01.u s01.v s01.w s01.x s01.y
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     9     9    10     0     4     2     2
#> 2     6     1     4     2     3     3     3
#> 3     5     4     4     9    10     5     8
#> 4     2     9     4     4     9     0     3
#> 5     8     3     9     2     8    10     2

select(new_df,contains("01"))
#>   s01.tot
#> 1      36
#> 2      22
#> 3      45
#> 4      31
#> 5      42

Created on 2024-07-23 with reprex v2.1.0
